# How to get "Yesterday 17th May 2015" format in moment.js

Tags: momentjs, momentics

I need to format some days in the format "Yesterday 17th May 2015" using moment.js. This is what I have so far:

```
var asd = moment(moment.utc("2015-09-30T08:35:40.59"))
          .subtract(1, 'days')
          .calendar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [Calendar customization doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/) is it possibile to customize the format of calendar.

In the example below, I customized the `sameElse` format of `calendar` for the English locale to return a string with the format you required:

```js
moment.locale('en', {
    calendar : {
        sameElse : '[Yesterday] Do MMM YYYY'
    }
});

var asd = moment.utc("2015-09-30T08:35:40.59")
          .subtract(1, 'days')
          .calendar();

console.log(asd);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: i want both today and as well for yesterday , will this work for both scenarios if i add today inside calendar?

Comment: You need to add the seme format for the key `sameDay` in `moment.locale('en', { calenda: {..}});`.